# List all the words in a text file with occurrence counts?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Suppose I have file `text.txt` as below:

`she likes cats, and he likes cats too.`

I'd like my result to look like:

```
she 1
likes 2
cats 2
and 1
he 1
too 1
```

If putting `space , .` into it would make the scripts easier, that would be fine.

Is there a simple shell pipeline that could achieve this?

Comment: If the phrase was "One of my cats weights 500lbs, that cat's super-sized!" - is that one count of cat plus one count of cats or something else? is there a word "s" to be counted in that sentence? Is there a word "500" and a word "lbs" or a word "500lbs" or something else? Is there a word "super" and a word "sized" or a word "super-sized"?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a one-liner near and dear to my heart:

```
cat text.txt | sed 's|[,.]||g' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

The sed strips punctuation (tune regex to taste), the tr puts the results one word per line.

Comment: UUOC and the sed will join "foo,bar" into one word "foobar".

Comment: Fair point. Using a pattern like `'s|[,.]| |g'`, where the replacement pattern includes whitespace, would avoid those concatenations.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk you can just specify the Record Separator (RS) to be any sequence of non-alphabetic characters:

```
$ gawk -v RS='[^[:alpha:]]+' '{sum[$0]++} END{for (word in sum) print word,sum[word]}' file
she 1
likes 2
and 1
too 1
he 1
cats 2
```

but that won't solve your problem of how to identify "words" in general.